# Express mysql connection err Error: connect ETIMEDOUT on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, express, xampp

I am doing mysql connection on express. I am using xampp on macos. When i create connection, return **( err Error: connect ETIMEDOUT )** error.  How can i solve this problem?

**connection code;**

```
 const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

      const connection = await mysql.createPool({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "xyz",
        port:8080
      });

 const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM users', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the default port to 3306.

```
const connection = await mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "xyz",
    port:3306
  });
```